# Change cursor on chart datapoint in web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

I am using asp.net charts in my web application.
All the data points are clickable.
I used MapAreaAttributes of each point to call a javascript function "onclick" event.

I want to change the cursor to pointer on mouse over event of the data points.
I tried:

```
chart.Series["series"].Points[i].MapAreaAttributes += "onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.cursor='default'\"";
```

but it doesn't work.

Anyone has a solution for that?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Inbal

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in prepaint event . As I have done it for my custom tooltip by calling javascript method onmouseover

```
<asp:Chart ID="ChartEXCEL" OnPrePaint="ChartEXCEL_Load" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="300px" Height="200px" runat="server">
```

```
protected void Chart1_Load(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChartElement is Series)
    {

        Series series = (Series)e.ChartElement;
        System.Drawing.PointF position = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;


        series.MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"showTooltip('#VALY-#VALX');\"";


    }
}
```